# WPF Combobox Entity Framework Binding (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, combobox

I am using the EntityFramework library in my WPF Application and I am having the following issue:
I am using the MVVM pattern (to the best of my knowledge) and I am trying to make a Combobox Lookup with EF values.

- I have a Company class which contains many Offices (a class as well)
- This has been modelled through the EntityFramework and all the links are correct (Office has a CompanyName which is a foreign key).

Here is the OfficeView class:

```
public partial class AddOffice : Window
{
    private DBHelper.ResourceManagementContext context = new DBHelper.ResourceManagementContext();
    public AddOffice()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        context.Companies.Load(); 
        this.DataContext = context.Companies.Local; 
        //this.DataContext = new AddOfficeViewModel();
    }

    public void CloseCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is the corresponding XAML:

```
  <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10">Company:</Label>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName"
              SelectedValuePath="CompanyName"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CompanyName}"/>
```

I know the MVVM pattern usually passes a ViewModel to the View so how would I accomplish binding the EntityFramework Company list to the ComboBox using the OfficeViewModel?

I understand the ComboBox properties. I know the selected value would be the CompanyName from the Office object and the SeletecValuePath would be the CompanyName from the Company object.

Comment: if you set the datacontext to .Local you should show us the code from this class. from the xaml you posted - .Local is some type of collection and each item within this collection should have at least a public property CompanyName.  is thats the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In View Model:

```
    class OfficeViewModel
{

    private string _CompanyName;

    public string CompanyName
    {
        get
        {
            return _CompanyName;
        }
        set
        {
            _CompanyName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CompanyName");
        }
    }

    private List<Location> _CompanyList;

    public List<Location> CompanyList
    {
        get
        {
            return _CompanyList;
        }
        set
        {
            _CompanyList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CompanyList");
        }
    }

    public List<Company> GetCompanyList()
    {
        return (from comp in Entity.Companies select comp).ToList(); 
    }
}
```

In Xaml:

Add the namespace in xaml as follows:

```
xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:WpfMvvmApplication.ViewModels"
```

Add the following in window.resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ViewModels:OfficeViewModel x:Key="OfficeController"/>       
</Window.Resources>
```

Bind the View Model to combobox:

```
 <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10">Company:</Label>
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CompanyList, Source={StaticResource OfficeController}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName"
          SelectedValuePath="CompanyName"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CompanyName}"/>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Perfect! I changed the GetCompanyList() to a void and called it from the constructor of my OfficeViewModel. Is this ok?

Comment: Yes you can call in that way too.